# Why doesn't it pads the space characters correctly when there are foreign characters?

Tags: hadoop, hive, data-warehouse

My goal is to export a file with fixed-width columns. I have the following HQL:

```
insert overwrite table destination_table
select concat(rpad(p.artist_name,40," "),rpad(p.release_name,40," "))
from source_table;
```

"destination_table" is an external table which writes to a file. When artist_name and release_name contains normal English characters, no problem, the result is the following:

```
paulo kuong[29 space characters]I am terribly stuck album
```

I got 40 charaters fixed width columns. However, when the strings are not English, I got:

```
장재인[31 space characters]다른 누구도 아닌 너에게
```

Which suppose to be 37 space characters. LPAD seems not able to pad the spaces correctly. When I do "length(장재인)" it returns 3 characters.. So there is something weird going on with lpad and rpad in HIVE

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I thought the `rpad` works as expected. According to the documents,

```
rpad(string str, int len, string pad) 
#Returns str, right-padded with pad to a length of len
```

So, in your case the length of `장재인[31 space characters]` should be 40.

In short the length of `장재인` should be 9.

---

I did a check in `python`, it then length of `장재인` is indeed 9.

```
>>> a = '장재인'
>>> len(a)
9
```

Comment: sorry the problem still hasn't been solved. When I do "length(장재인)" it returns 3 characters.. So there is something weird going on with lpad and rpad in HIVE

Comment: How did you do `length(장재인)`